# What is the purpose of DropGuard in LinkedList::drain_filter::drop?

Tags: rust

I was looking at the drop implementation of DrainFilter to make sure that it removes all remaining elements, and I noticed that it has a DropGuard for self (which is the DrainFilter iterator) around each `drop(item);`. What's the point of this guard? Unless the `drop(item);` call panics, I don't see the purpose of it. Is it just to ensure that the rest of the items are removed even if a panic occurs? Why not use catch_unwind?

Relevant drop impl:

```rust
impl<T, F> Drop for DrainFilter<'_, T, F>
where
    F: FnMut(&mut T) -> bool,
{
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        struct DropGuard<'r, 'a, T, F>(&'r mut DrainFilter<'a, T, F>)
        where
            F: FnMut(&mut T) -> bool;

        impl<'r, 'a, T, F> Drop for DropGuard<'r, 'a, T, F>
        where
            F: FnMut(&mut T) -> bool,
        {
            fn drop(&mut self) {
                self.0.for_each(drop);
            }
        }

        while let Some(item) = self.next() {
            let guard = DropGuard(self);
            drop(item);
            mem::forget(guard);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Why not use catch_unwind?"_ This would involve capturing the error and then correctly re-panicking. The approach here doesn't need to capture and re-panic at all, so I would say it's better. catch_unwind would be similar to a catch block that cleans up and re-throws in other languages, while the drop guard is closer to a finally block. The latter makes more sense here. _However,_ it looks like this will catch _at most one_ panic while dropping remaining items. From what I can see, if there is a second panic then the remaining items are leaked.

Comment: @cdhowie If there is a second panic the process is aborted.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Right, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is to protect from the case where the destructor of `item` panics. This pattern is used several times across the standard library (and also in foreign crates).

`catch_unwind()` has two disadvantages:

1. Drop guards are more optimizable than `catch_unwind()`. They're almost always optimized correctly in the happy path, while `catch_unwind()` does not. In addition, they're also less costly on the panic path, because no need to `resume_unwind()`.
2. Double panics. If the destructor of another element panics while we're in the middle of panic, what happens? With drop guards, this is a hard abort. This is in line with the rest of the language, where double panic causes a hard abort. However, with `catch_unwind()`, using the easy way (`catch_unwind()` + cleanup code + `resume_unwind()`) this causes the first panic to be ignored, which is not what users would probably expect, and handling this correctly requires a double `catch_unwind()`.